# Booking meeting rooms; Select available rooms in a given time period

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a meeting rooms booking system, where you choose a certain period of time and you should get available rooms at that time.
some of the tables s names are in french so i'll provide the meaning between () when needed.
My problem is that when i pick a time i get even not available rooms as available. and i think my query has some problems.
So, i have a reservation table,professor table and salle (means room in french) table.
The reservation table has the following columns : idReservation, dateReservation, hDebut (which is the starting time of the meeting),
hFin(ending time), idSalle (room id)

Here are the create tables queries : please comment if you didn't understand some of the columns name who may be, like i said in french.

```
CREATE TABLE `reservation` (
  `idReservation` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dateReservation` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `hDebut` time NOT NULL,
  `hFin` time NOT NULL,
  `dateModificationReservation` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `motifReservation` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `idSalle` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idProf` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `etatreserv` int(10) NOT NULL
)
```

etatreserv (2 for waiting, 1 for rejected, 0 for accepted)stands for the state of the room since the user send a request of booking a room for a cetrain time and the admin has the option to accept/reject even if the room is available

```
INSERT INTO `reservation`(`idReservation`, `dateReservation`, `hDebut`, `hFin`, `dateModificationReservation`, `motifReservation`, `idSalle`, `idProf`, `etatreserv`) VALUES (1,'2019-06-14','15:00:00','18:00:00','2019-06-09','administrative meeting',1,12,2)
```

```
CREATE TABLE `salle` (
  `idSalle` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `intitule` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `NumeroSalle` int(255) NOT NULL
)
```

```
INSERT INTO `salle` (`idSalle`, `intitule`, `NumeroSalle`) VALUES
(1, 'salle de reunion 1', 1),
(10, 'salle 18', 18);
```

```
CREATE TABLE `professeur` (
  `idProf` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nomProf` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `prenomProf` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `tel` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `profpwd` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `dateAddProf` date NOT NULL,
  `dateModificationProf` date NOT NULL,
  `idDepart` int(11) NOT NULL
)
```

```
INSERT INTO `professeur` (`idProf`, `nomProf`, `prenomProf`, `tel`, `email`, `profpwd`, `dateAddProf`, `dateModificationProf`, `idDepart`) VALUES
(12, 'ddd', 'dd', 444, 'email@email.com', 'pwd', '2019-06-05', '2019-06-05', 5);
```

what i have tried already :

```
SELECT * FROM reservation left OUTER JOIN salle on reservation.idSalle = salle.idSalle WHERE (
    (reservation.dateReservation IS NULL) 
    OR 
    (reservation.dateReservation != ':dateReservation')
     OR 
     ((reservation.dateReservation = ':dateReservation') AND (reservation.hDebut NOT BETWEEN ':hDebut' AND ':hFin') AND (reservation.hFin NOT BETWEEN ':hDebut' AND ':hFin'))
      OR
       ((reservation.dateReservation = ':dateReservation') AND (reservation.hDebut >':hDebut' AND  reservation.hFin <':hFin'))   
     )
```

and then  i tried a more simplified version :

````
    dateReservation = ':dateReservation' AND
    (hDebut BETWEEN ':hDebut' AND ':hFin' OR hFin BETWEEN ':hDebut' AND ':hFin' OR
    (hDebut < ':hDebut' AND hFin > ':hFin'))))```

example : 
salle table 
idSalle | name
1       |salle de reunion 1
10      |salle18
3       |salle3 

reservation table 
idReservation|dateReservation|hDebut   |hFin     |idSalle
1            |2019-06-14     |15:00:00 |18:00:00 |1

if for example  i choose dateReservation = 2019-06-14, hDebut=16:00:00,
hFin = 17:00:00 then all i should see are : salle2 and salle3 

PS : I'm new to stackoverflow and the syntax highlighting confused me a bit, so I'm sorry if my code doesn't show up as it should.
````

Comment: And what is the problem? What is your question?

Comment: Oh sorry, my problem is that when i pick a time i get even  not available rooms as available. i guess my query has some problems

Comment: Usually you just create an account that always accept meetings unless it's already booked. I'm quite sure that function exists in Outlook. At least that is what I believe all companies I have worked for has solved it.

Answer (score 1):

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS salle;

    CREATE TABLE salle 
    (salle_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
    ,name VARCHAR(12) UNIQUE
    );

    INSERT INTO salle VALUES
    (1,'salle1'),
    (2,'salle2'),
    (3,'salle3');


    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS reservation ;

    CREATE TABLE reservation 
    (reservation_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
    ,reservation_from DATETIME NOT NULL
    ,reservation_to DATETIME NULL
    ,salle_id INT NOT NULL
    );

    INSERT INTO reservation VALUES
    (1,'2019-06-14 15:00:00','2019-06-14 18:00:00',1);

    SELECT s.*
      FROM salle s
      LEFT 
      JOIN reservation r
        ON r.salle_id = s.salle_id
       AND reservation_from <= '2019-06-14 17:00:00'
       AND reservation_to  >= '2019-06-14 16:00:00'
     WHERE r.reservation_id IS NULL;

+----------+--------+
| salle_id | name   |
+----------+--------+
|        2 | salle2 |
|        3 | salle3 |
+----------+--------+
```

Comment: what do you mean with reservation_from & reservation_to since it s giving me an error : Unknown column 'reservation_from' in 'on clause' . actually i didn't understand what u mean with the query.

Comment: I guess  i understood what the query is doing !I will try re rerwite it and test.  thank you !

Comment: The second part of the query finds all rows that match the criteria. The first part says 'yep, I don't want those'